# How can i add Manual Shipping and Handling Cost Instead of Using Webshop-Matrix Rate

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, table-rates

I need to **add manual Shipping and Handling cost**, the problem is I am using **webshops_Matrix rate**, which is automatically calculate Shipping and Handling cost based on **Weight and Zip Code**. When I manually add order from back end I can't add manual cost of shipping and handling cost.

How can I add Manual Shipping and Handling cost.

Comment: Try this extension https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/flat-rate-shipping-per-product-6.html it will work for manual shipping method for each product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [this extension](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-ship-price.html) to set shipping price from admin.

This extension is only for admin and not available for frontend. This extension will allow you to set **shiipping price** and **shipping title** at the time of order creation from Admin.

Comment: After installation, what can i do at back end

Comment: Nothing, Just enable that shipping method and create order from admin and check

Comment: @ Ashish Jagnani : Like same is any module available for set Payment Price from admin

Comment: @ Ashish Jagnani : Like this https://snag.gy/Vqx9wE.jpg